# Sum of Second Derivatives and its relation to Local Minima

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

**Question:**

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ be an open set. If $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{C}^2$, and has the following property:
$$D_{11}f+D_{22}f+\dots + D_{nn}f < 0 \quad \forall x \in E$$
show that it can't have any local minima in $E$. You can use the first and second derivative tests for single variable functions.

**Solution:**

I'm unsure how to make what I have rigorous, but my idea would be to say that if we take the restriction of $f$ to each "axis", we would have single-valued functions. Were we to have a minimum at a point x, then these functions would have themselves a minimum at this point and $D_{ii}f|_{x_i}>0$. Then, the sum of these would be positive, not negative as stated in the question. Is this rigorous?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $f:E \to \Bbb R$?  Otherwise, how is $\sum_1^n D_{ii}f$  defined, how is if $< 0$?  Cheers!

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've edited it.

Comment: I still think you need $f:\Bbb R^n \supset E \to \Bbb R$; if $f:\Bbb R \supset E \to \Bbb R$, what to all the $D_{ii}f, \; 1 \le i \le n$, mean?

Comment: I had edited it incorrectly. You are right.

Comment: Now it's lookin' good!